# spring-boot-starter-mail connecting to mail server every 30 seconds

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I just added spring-boot-starter-mail to spring-boot application to send mail.

The send mail is working, but when I set this flag to true `spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true` logs show spring-boot application connect to mail server every 30 seconds.

How to make spring-boot application only connect to the mail server only when sending mail?

every 30 seconds the logs show this:

```
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
QUIT
221 Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be spring actuator

application is deployed on cloud with load balancer health checks calling `/actuator/health` every 30 seconds

I disabled mail health check with application.yml

```
management:
  health:
    mail:
      enabled: false
```